# Wordpress 4.0 installing theme failed?

Tags: wordpress, themes

i download wordpress 4.0 from wordpress.org but i cannot install any themes with this version.?
it show error: 
Downloading install package from http://wordpress.org/themes/download/bluesip.1.3.5.zip…

Warning: unlink(C:\Windows\TEMP/bluesip5.tmp) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in G:\AppServ\www\itcode\wp-admin\includes\file.php on line 457
Download failed. error:0D0C50A1:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_item_verify:unknown message digest algorithm

how can i fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message. I am not sure why the error message occurs. However, here is a workaround to manually install the wordpress theme.

1. Download the theme zip file  http://wordpress.org/themes/download/bluesip.1.3.5.zip
2. Extract the theme zip file to the wordpress themes folder wordpress\wp-content\themes

Once you have extracted the folder to themes, login to the wordpress admin and click on Appearance.
The theme will be automatically loaded there. Click on the "Install" button next to the theme and the theme will be installed.

Hope this helps!